# How to avoid "ORA-00936: missing expression" when selecting required column(s) first then remaining columns without giving column names

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select columname,* from tablename
```

```
error
-----
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is caused by the use of the asterisk without a table prefix.

While it IS valid to use `select * from tablename`, in Oracle, if you add a column into that query you **MUST specify what table the asterisk refers to** like this `select columname1, tablename.* from tablename`. This is demonstrated below:

> ```
> CREATE table tablename (
>     columnname1 INT,
>     columnname2 DATE,
>     columnname3 FLOAT
> );
> ```

> ```
> select columnname1,* from tablename
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-00936: missing expression
> ```

> ```
> select columnname1, tablename.* from tablename
> ```
>
> ```
> COLUMNNAME1 | COLUMNNAME1 | COLUMNNAME2 | COLUMNNAME3
> ----------: | ----------: | :---------- | ----------:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=57ec3d71659059d8110caa26aed91a65)*

This also applies to table aliases, this will still fail

```
select columnname1,* from tablename t1
```

but this is valid

```
select columnname1,t1.* from tablename t1
```

Answer (score 1):

use an alias

```sql
select columname,t1.* from tablename t1
```